# Error when trying to place input$something in front of "=" sign in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the `shiny` app below in which I want to run the function `detect_value_range_violations()` but instead of the `lifecycle` in line 27 I want to put `input$sel` to change between `lifecycle` and `qty` but then I get error `detect_value_range_violations(input$sel =`

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(daqapo)
act<-structure(list(lifecycle = c(3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 6, 6, 4, 4, 5, 
                             5), qty = c(31, 31, 31, NA, 9, 31, 28, 28, 6, 6, 3, 3)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                    -12L), class = c("activitylog", "log", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                                    ), case_id = "case_id", activity_id = "activity", resource_id = "resource", timestamps = c("start", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "complete"))
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput("sel","Select",choices = colnames(act),selected = colnames(act)[1],multiple = F)
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    
      ))


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  valuerange<-reactive({
    vr<-act %>%
      detect_value_range_violations(
        #input$sel
        lifecycle = domain_numeric(from = 0, to = 5))
    
  })
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with shiny specifically. You could reduce your example to just `varname = 'lifecycle'; detect_value_range_violations(varname = domain_numeric(from = 0, to = 5))`. The problem is R doesn't allow variable names for parameter names when calling a function.

Comment: the value should be taken from the selectInput() (input$sel). it will be either lifecycle or qty

Comment: Yes but `input$sel` is just a character value. You'd have the same problem not using shiny and just using a regular character value to try to specify the name.

Comment: how can I choose lifecycle or qty instead of only lifecycle?

Comment: someone might ask me why would I use it like a character then, this is why i combined it with shiny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `detect_value_range_violations` seems to use `rlang` under the hood so you can use the `:=` operator to change parameters names. I can't get your example to run without error so I'll use the example from the help page for that function.

```
data("hospital_actlog")

varname <- "triagecode"
# varname <- input$sel  #--- would also work

detect_value_range_violations(activitylog = hospital_actlog,
     "{varname}" := domain_numeric(from = 0, to = 5))
```